# How can I add custom keyboard on my Telegram bot?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

Here is my Telegram bot code:

```
import time, datetime
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop

now = datetime.datetime.now()

def action(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    print('Received: %s' % command)

    if command == '/start':
        telegram_bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("Hi!"))
        telegram_bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(now.hour)+str(":")+str(now.minute))
    elif command == 'Time':
        telegram_bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(now.hour)+str(":")+str(now.minute))
    elif command == 'Logo':
        telegram_bot.sendPhoto (chat_id, photo = "https://i.pinimg.com/avatars/circuitdigest_1464122100_280.jpg")
    elif command == 'File':
        telegram_bot.sendDocument(chat_id, document=open('/home/pi/sendbot.py'))
    elif command == 'Audio':
        telegram_bot.sendAudio(chat_id, audio=open('/home/pi/test.mp3'))

telegram_bot = telepot.Bot('MY-BOT-TOKEN')
print((telegram_bot.getMe()))

MessageLoop(telegram_bot, action).run_as_thread()
print('Up and Running....')

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

I want to add a custom keyboard for this bot that will have 4 buttons named `Time`, `Logo`, `File` and `Audio`.

As examples If I click on the `Time` button instead of typing "Time", it will tell me the time. 
If I click on the `Logo` button instead of typing it, it will send me the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good examples in the [Telepot's Github project](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/tree/master/examples). check them out plz.

```
...
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[['Time', KeyboardButton(text='Logo')],["File", "Audio"]])
    if command == '/start':
        telegram_bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("Hi! Which one do you want? choose from the below keyboard buttons."), reply_markup=markup)
        telegram_bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(now.hour)+str(":")+str(now.minute))
...
```

Comment: I have added those lines getting error. What to import?

Comment: There are 2 things you may need to import: from telepot.namedtuple import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton